# Distribution of the number of prime factors

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Count the number of prime factors of a number $n$
to include multiplicity,
so that
$$n=24=2^3 \cdot 3 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$$
has $4$ prime factors, and
$$n =
6500 =
2^2 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 13 =
2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 13
$$
has $6$ prime factors.

The distribution is quite regular.
Here it is for $n \le n_\max$, $n_\max=10^7$:

---

[image: DistPrimeFacts]

         

<sup>About a quarter of $n \le 10^7$ have $3$ prime factors.</sup>

---

> ***Q***. What is this distribution explicitly?
>   Where is its peak, for $n \le n_\max$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191698/is-there-a-pattern-for-the-distribution-of-prime-factor-count-for-numbers-under

Comment: Although the poster Joe in Carlo's link is of course not Joseph O'Rourke! :-)

Comment: I can't add comments since this account is new, but for those wondering. For sufficiently large numbers, there is a point when 4 overtakes 3 as the peak in the discrete graph. I am referring to an answer in the following question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3547453

Comment: @Ubersehen I converted it to a comment for you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

this variable $\Omega(n)$, the number of prime factors of $n$ counting multiplicity, has for large $n$ a normal distribution with mean [*] $1+\log(\log n)$ and standard deviation $[\log(\log n)]^{1/2}$; see, for example, [Prime Numbers and Computer Methods for Factorization](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Prime_Numbers_and_Computer_Methods_for_F.html?id=5cIN7kemQgYC&redir_esc=y), page 167 [first edition], page 159 [second edition].

[*] more precisely, this additive constant 1 should be replaced by $1.03465\ldots$ as calculated by [Knuth and Trabb-Pardo](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(76)90050-5) (appendix A); incidentally, if we don't count multiplicities the normal distribution has mean $0.26+\log(\log n)$ with the same standard deviation $[\log(\log n)]^{1/2}$, so the only difference is a slight displacement of the whole curve.

---

--- update 2020, in response to query:

the "0.26" number is defined as
$$c_1= \gamma+\sum_{p\;\text{prime}}\biggl(\log(1-1/p)+\frac{1}{p}\biggr)= 0.261497212847643$$
while the "1.03" number is defined as
$$c_2=\gamma+\sum_{p\;\text{prime}}\biggl(\log(1-1/p)+\frac{1}{p-1}\biggr)= 1.034653881897438$$
The number $c_1$ is known as the [Meissel-Mertens constant.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant)
Both $c_1$ and $c_2$ are referred to as [Hadamard-de la Vallée-Poussin constants](https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/h/h017.htm) (see also this [MathWorld entry).](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensConstant.html)

Comment: Thats very interesting, I initially started looking into this to see if it peaked at e. Thanks for linking this!

Comment: Is there a formula for the distribution seen above?

Comment: @Joe --- sure, when $n$ goes to infinity it is a Gaussian with the mean and variance indicated in the answer;

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Can you write down the exact distribution which would be useful for us?

Comment: This question has gotten a bit old, but is this $0.26$ the Meissel-Mertens constant?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN -- yes it is, I have added this to the answer.

Comment: These are [A083342](http://oeis.org/A083342) and [A077761](http://oeis.org/A077761),