# Behavior of the "mean prime factor" of numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

This question concerns the behavior of
a function $f(\;)$ that maps each number in $\mathbb{N}$ to
its *mean prime factor*.
I previously posted premature questions, now deleted, which
explains the cites below to several who contributed observations.
Also, the question, "[Distribution of the number of prime factors](https://mathoverflow.net/q/220037/6094),"
may be relevant.

Define $f(n)$ to be the floor of the geometric mean of
all the prime factors of $n$.
For example,
$$n = 6500 = 2^2 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 13 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 13
\;.$$
$$f(6500) = \lfloor\left(
2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 13
\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\rfloor
= \lfloor 4.32 \rfloor = 4
\;.
$$
For $n$ a prime, $f(n) = n$, i.e., the primes are fixed points of $f(\;)$.
For $n$ a prime power $p^k$, $f(n)=p$ (as Julian Rosen observed).
Greg Martin noted that
$$
f(n) = \lfloor n ^ {1/\Omega(n)} \rfloor
$$
where $\Omega(n)$ is the number of primes dividing
$n$ counted with multiplicity.

I explored $|f^{-1}(k)|$, the number of $n \in \mathbb{N}$
that map to $k$: $f(n)=k$.
The root transition points are crucial (as Gerhard Paseman emphasized).
For $n_\max=10^7$, the square-root, cube-root, and fourth-roots
of $n_\max$ are $(3163,216,57)$ rounded up.
Here are graphs of $|f^{-1}|$ at two scales:

---

[image: Sqrt]

         

<sup>$n_\max=10^7$. Note the transitions at $216$ and $3163$.</sup>

---

[image: Cbrt]

         

<sup>$n_\max=10^7$. Note the transitions at $57$ and at $216$.</sup>

---

> ***Q***.
>   What explains the apparent linearity in the first graph
>   in the range $[216,3163]$, in contrast to the gradual
>   upsweep in the range $[57,216]$ in the second graph?

I did not expect to see such regularity...

Comment: It seems to me that the first graph is counting integers in $[k^2,(k+1)^2]$ with two prime factors, and the length of the interval is linear in $k$.  The second graph weighs heavily numbers with three prime factors in the interval $[k^3,(k+1)^3]$ and the length of this interval is quadratic in $k$.  (In the second case you may also be counting numbers with two prime factors, and this would muddy the quadratic feature a little bit.)

Comment: Thanks, @Lucia. That makes sense, and seems to explain the linear vs quadratic behavior.